# How to read certain sets of lines from a big data file in python?

Tags: python, header, row

Let us say that I have a data file which includes repeated headers. The rows I need to read are included between `#` and `_` as follwoing:

```
Header :Hellow World  
Header :Hellow World
#
0.326681 11.7083 0 
4.34818 12.222 0 
7.56993 12.5076 0 
5.55984 11.798 0 
6.77682 11.7432 0 
4.44614 11.0851 0 
6.77111 10.4761 0 
_
Header :Hellow World  
Header :Hellow World
#
0.126018 2.98437 0 
0.855801 3.76535 0 
0.216594 0.154549 0 
4.38824 1.92399 0 
5.67207 1.28992 0 
5.28882 0.231295 0 
_
etc....
```

I wrote a code in order to just extract the rows between `#` and `_` and to write `#i'th_list` before each list. The point is that my code runs forever in the terminal without stopping. Can anyone help me understand my problem ?

```
f=open("f1.txt","w")
ff=open("f2.txt","r")

parsing=False
i=0
for line in ff:
    if line.startswith("#"):
        parsing=True
        f.write("#"+str(i)+"\n")
        i=i+1
    while parsing==True:
        f.write(ff.readline())
        if line.startswith("_"):
            break
    parsing=False 

ff.close()
f.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that your code would never left the "while parsing==True" loop.
I also don't know what the readline() method does but it seems that it doesnt fit in your code.
Working Code:

```
f=open("f1.txt","w")
ff=open("f2.txt","r")

parsing=False
i=0
for line in ff:
    if line.startswith("#"):
        parsing=True
        f.write("#"+str(i)+"\n")
        i=i+1
        continue
    if parsing:
        if line.startswith("_"):
            parsing=False
            continue
        f.write(line) 

ff.close()
f.close()
```

Ps: dont forget the brackets at ff.close() ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you are reading line using `ff.readline()` function but on next line of code you are using different 'line' to check if it starts with '_' or not.

```
f=open("f1.txt","w")
ff=open("no_header.txt","r")

parsing=False
i=0
for line in ff:
    if line.startswith("#"):
        parsing=True
        f.write("#"+str(i)+"\n")
        i=i+1
    while parsing==True:
        # Your code was not correct from this point
        current_line = ff.readline()
        if current_line.startswith("_"):
            break
        f.write(current_line)
    parsing=False 

ff.close()
f.close
```

Comment: The code did not read the whole file opened as "ff". Therefore, the file opened as f was not completely written. @Sven's answer works perfectly.

Comment: My code works fine too. Only difference is @Sven wrote almost whole new code. I made minimal changes to your code so that you can understand better.